# contour integral and limit: What is the condition of the interchange the order?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, limits

In real real analysis sense, the interchange between limit and integral is hold when 
integrand is uniformly converges. 
$i.e$ 
\begin{align}
\int \lim f = \lim \int f
\end{align}

Here i want to extend this to complex analysis. $i.e$ contour integral and limit 
\begin{align}
 \oint \lim f = \lim \oint f
\end{align}
In the text related with complex analysis, i found that this also holds 
and the integrand is uniformly converge.

---

How about analyticity of $f$? 
Does it related with interchange of limit and integral?

Comment: a contour is homeomorphic to a circle, the exchange of lim and integral continue to works. For analyticity, look at the wiki entry for [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem), In particular, the part about uniform limits of analytic functions.